# Using PL/SQL to update a table based on another tables

Tags: sql, plsql

So i have this table **A**

| ENTITY_ID | DOCUMENT_ID | CREATE_DATE | CAPITAL_STOCK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX123456789 | WQE | 17.08.02 | 1000 |
| XX123456789 | AXC | 18.12.05 | 1000 |
| XX123456789 | MKU | 19.07.04 | 1000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

This table **B**

| ENTITY_ID | LCOMPANY_CODE |
| --- | --- |
| XX123456789 | 678 |
| ... | ... | ... |

And this table **C**

| LCOMPANY_CODE | CHANGE_DATE | CAPITAL_STOCK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 678 | 17.01.01 | 2000 |
| 678 | 18.01.01 | 4000 |
| 678 | 18.06.01 | 6500 |
| ... | ... | ... |

As you can see in `table C`, `CAPITAL_STOCK` changes at certains dates for the same `LCOMPANY_CODE`

**I want to update `A.CAPITAL_STOCK` with `C.CAPITAL_STOCK`  values**, but some points first:

1. The only way I have to link `Table A` and `table C`, is by `table B`, I can't simply update from `table C` to `table A`.
2. At `C.CHANGE_DATE 17.01.01`, `C.CAPITAL_STOCK` has value `2000`, and in `table A` has value `1000`. For example, in each row of table, whenever is found a row which `A.CREATE_DATE` is, IN THIS CASE, `between 17.01.01 and 17.12.31`, `A.CAPITAL_STOCK` has to have `value = 2000`. Whenever is found a row which `A.CREATE_DATE` is, between `18.01.01 and 18.05.31`, `A.CAPITAL_STOCK` has to have `value = 4000`, after `18.05.31` `CAPITAL_STOCK` should have `6500` value.

What's the best way to do this update?

I was thinking of using a PL/SQL block, fetching values to cursors, and then use a for loop to roam all records from A table and update with proper values, but is it the most simple solution? What is making me more confused is `A-C table` link, and then the update question...

Comment: You can solve this using Triggers. it may be easy

Comment: Can u be more specific, please? How can i struct that block of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using standard update syntax requires a correlated sub-query, and that requires a guarantee that only one value is returned.  In the following query that's achieved using `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` to fetch the most recent record on or before the input record's create date.

```
UPDATE
  table_a  a
SET
  capital_stock = (
    SELECT
      c.capital_stock
    FROM
      table_b   b
    INNER JOIN
      table_c   c
        ON c.lcompany_code  = b.lcompany_code
    WHERE
          b.entity_id    = a.entity_id
      AND c.change_date <= a.create_date
    ORDER BY
      c.change_date DESC
    FETCH
      FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
  )
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=22a1bef758e1fa65b0ebdc64e908ccad

One downside is that ***all*** records will be updated, ***even if they don't need to be***.

The general way to avoid that is to use a `MERGE`...

```
MERGE INTO
  table_a
USING
  (
    SELECT
      a.*,
      c.capital_stock   AS revised_capital_stock
    FROM
      table_a   a
    INNER JOIN
      table_b   b
        ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
    CROSS APPLY
    (
      SELECT capital_stock
        FROM table_c
       WHERE change_date   <= a.create_date
         AND lcompany_code  = b.lcompany_code
    ORDER BY change_date DESC
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
    )
      c
  )
    revision
      ON (    revision.entity_id   = table_a.entity_id
          AND revision.document_id = table_a.document_id
          AND revision.create_date = table_a.create_date
         )
WHEN
  MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET capital_stock = revision.revised_capital_stock
  WHERE
    capital_stock <> revision.revised_capital_stock
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b00017ed2a1a1bbced3f81557b06eb0c

*(In this demo I changed one starting value to demonstrate that rows do not get updated if not necessary; you can see it updates only two rows.)*

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake @MatBailie, I removed the original answer.

Comment: i'm running the script, when it finishes i'll give feedback

Comment: What i needed, thank you