# ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row - Problem

Tags: sql, oracle

I've this SQL query for updating a table based on another tables:

```
UPDATE table_a ao
SET capital_stock = 
(WITH
table_c_ec (company_code,change_date,cap_stock_changed, next_change_date) AS
(
SELECT company_code,change_date,cap_stock_changed, 
       LEAD(change_date,1,TO_DATE('14.01.01','YY.MM.DD')) OVER (PARTITION BY c.company_code order by  c.change_date) as next_change_date 
       FROM table_c c
)
SELECT c.cap_stock_changed 
  FROM table_a a 
       JOIN table_b b ON a.entity_id = b.lcompany_fiscal_num
       JOIN table_c_ec c ON b.lcompany_code = c.company_code AND a.create_date BETWEEN c.change_date AND c.next_change_date
 WHERE a.entity_id =ao.entity_id AND a.document_id = ao.document_id
);
```

After 8 hours of scripting, i got "ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row" ...

'Table a' has thousands and thousands of records in it, which are candidates to be changed with this update clause... What can i change to get rid of the error? I know that the 'IN' clause can possible solve this error in general, but i don't know if, in this case, can be applied

Comment: Well.. your subquery that starts with `WITH` is returning more than one value/row for some rows in the updated table. What do you want to do in those cases? Update with any value at random? Don't update? Pick the max value, the min one? At the moment Oracle is throwing an error since it doesn't know what to do. First, you need to decide what do you want to do in these cases; then the solution can be simple.

Comment: Can you please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266753/using-pl-sql-to-update-a-table-based-on-another-tables/70275721?noredirect=1#comment124278447_70275721) 
 i've made? There i explain my problem and what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Not sure what the relevance of that link is to what @TheImpaler has told you. You need to fix your SQL so that it only returns one record for each record in the ao table

Comment: In the link, is explained what i'm trying to update and how it's suppose to be made. Basically i want to update a column in table A with data from table C, but i've to consider some points

Comment: I replied to the original question - not sure what else to add - as others commented - you have mutliple rows in the ```WITH``` clause statement that are not there in your sample data. The database cannot update because you ask it to update a column to a value but it has multiple values available for that row. What do you want to happen in that case ? Once you figure that out, your question can be answered...

Comment: In Oracle, don't use UPDATE to modify thousands of rows. Use MERGE instead.

Comment: In the first SELECT clause i acquire the value of capital stock at that date, and when the value will be changed next. In the second SELECT clause, for each record in table A that is returned, f.ex, in table C, at the date '17.12.20' capital_stock value is 123456. At the date '18.12.05'  the value is 1234567, and in table A that value at date '18.12.06' still 123456, and that's not correct. It should be 1234567

Comment: @KoenLostrie - Your answer had a mistake, and is the cause of the error.  I modified the OP's example data so that one source row's create date matches one of the change dates, and that highlights the failure case : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0f412f3b0a36b6e8ec6ab9c51fa3b523 *(Alternative answers provided on OP's original question)*

Comment: @MatBailie thanks for the update, I removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `BETWEEN` is the mistake.

If the `create_date` exactly matches a `change_date` the input row will match ***two*** rows in `table_c`

I would also suggest a simplification of the code as follows *(using `MERGE` to avoid updating rows that are already correct)*.

```
MERGE INTO
  table_a
USING
  (
    SELECT
      a.*,
      c.capital_stock   AS revised_capital_stock
    FROM
      table_a   a
    INNER JOIN
      table_b   b
        ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
    CROSS APPLY
    (
      SELECT capital_stock
        FROM table_c
       WHERE change_date   <= a.create_date
         AND lcompany_code  = b.lcompany_code
    ORDER BY change_date DESC
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
    )
      c
  )
    revision
      ON (    revision.entity_id   = table_a.entity_id
          AND revision.document_id = table_a.document_id
          AND revision.create_date = table_a.create_date
         )
WHEN
  MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET capital_stock = revision.revised_capital_stock
  WHERE
    capital_stock <> revision.revised_capital_stock
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b00017ed2a1a1bbced3f81557b06eb0c